# difference between standard's atomic bool and atomic flag

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, atomic

I wasn't aware of the `std::atomic` variables but was aware about the `std::mutex` (weird right!) provided by the standard; however one thing caught my eye: there are two seemingly-same (to me) atomic types provided by the standard, listed below:

1. [`std::atomic<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)
2. [`std::atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag)

The `std::atomic_flag` contains the following explanation:

> `std::atomic_flag` is an atomic boolean type. Unlike all specializations of `std::atomic`, it is guaranteed to be lock-free. Unlike `std::atomic<bool>`, `std::atomic_flag` does not provide load or store operations.

which I fail to understand. Is `std::atomic<bool>` not guaranteed to be lock-free? Then it's not atomic or what?

So what's the difference between the two and when should I use which?

Comment: "Atomic" and "lock-free" aren't synonyms. You can easily be lock-free without being atomic (that's what happens when you don't do any synchronization, for example :P), and you can easily have an atomic operation that isn't lock-free (for example, using a monitor).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> std::atomic bool type not guranteed to be lock-free?

Correct. `std::atomic` may be implemented using locks.

> then it's not atomic or what?

`std::atomic` is atomic whether it has been implemented using locks, or without. `std::atomic_flag` is guaranteed to be implemented without using locks.

> So what's the difference b/w two

The primary difference besides the lock-free guarantee is:

> `std::atomic_flag` does not provide load or store operations.

---

> and when should I use which?

Usually, you will want to use `std::atomic<bool>` when you need an atomic boolean variable. `std::atomic_flag` is a low level structure that can be used to implement custom atomic structures.

Comment: If the target architecture supports atomic operations, there would be no reason to use locks. But if it doesn't, I wonder *how* would `std::atomic_flag` be implemented then?

Comment: [for edit] yes because load and store might not be relevant with boolean `std::atomic` but will be with other types.

Comment: @RustyX: all existing architectures support at least atomic load-and-set-word (or equivalent negated load-and-clear-word), which is enough to implement `std::atomic_flag`, but not much more. See PA-RISC, where `ldcw` is the only atomic RMW op.

Comment: @RustyX: Hypothetically, it couldn't, and that would be the end of it. But as Fanael says that's not a problem in reality.

Comment: And for `std::atomic` you need CAS I guess... clear, thanks!

Comment: @RustyX Actually, you don't need hardware support to provide lock-free atomicity - there are algorithms that can do this safely. However, one of the main reasons to use lock-free code in the first place is to improve performance over heavily contented data/code - and those algorithms are much slower than a lock. `std::atomic` does that choice for you based on the architecture you're compiling for. `std::atomic_flag` is "I totally, absolutely need lock-free, no matter how much it costs".

Comment: @Luaan: You need lock-free atomics for signal-handling, because you cannot use a lock to protect state shared with a signal-handler without risking self-deadlock.

Comment: @EOF: These lock-free operations however, only need to be asynchronous-signal safe and not thread-safe (assuming there are multiple hardware threads). That said, you would typically use thread-safe atomic operations to implement a lock in the first place, so any hardware that supports multiple hardware threads but no thread-safe atomic operations like test and set is most certainly brain-damaged.

Comment: @ArneVogel state shared between signal handlers and normal execution only needs to be `volatile sig_atomic_t` **iff** only one thread is accessing the state, and that thread is also the only thread that can be signaled. Otherwise, you certainly need thread-safe atomics for shared mutable state accessed in signal handler context.

Answer (score 26):

`std::atomic<T>` guarantees that accesses to the variable will be atomic. It however does not says how is the atomicity achieved. It can be using lock-free variable, or using a lock. The actual implementation depends on your target architecture and the type `T`.

`std::atomic_flag` on the other hand is guaranteed to be implemented using a lock-free technique.