# The proper way of terminating the worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Hi I am trying to find out the best peaceful way of terminating a worker thread. I have the following code:

```
class test{
  public:
test() {}
~test() {}

std::atomic<bool> worker_done;


int a;
void pr() {
    while (true) {
        if (worker_done) {
            break;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        printf("%d \n", a++);
    }
}

std::thread* m_acqThread;
void continuous() {
    m_acqThread = new std::thread(&test::pr, this);
}

void stopThread(){
    if (m_acqThread) {
        if (m_acqThread->joinable())
            m_acqThread->join();
        delete m_acqThread;
        m_acqThread = nullptr;
    }
}


};


int main(){

test t;
t.continuous();

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
t.worker_done = true;

t.stopThread();


std::string str;
std::cin.clear();
getline(std::cin, str);
return 0;
```

Is there a better way of notifying the worker's thread to be terminated other than setting "worker_done" to be true ?

Thanks

Comment: "...best peaceful way..." Is there a violent way?

Comment: Please use `unique_ptr` instead of manual pointer tracking.

Comment: non-hostile kill is what I think the term he/she meant

Comment: `std::thread` does not have an interface for that. Either use the brutal methods or a flag.

Comment: No. The worker thread needs to know you want it to end. So a signal must be sent.

Comment: BTW you don't need to use a pointer for your thread, just use it as a value object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is fine: if you have a `thread` that say starts when your program opens, and as your program closes you need to stop it, using an `atomic<bool>` is the right way to do this.

It's possible to also use [`std::atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) like so:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

std::atomic_flag lock;
int n = 0;

void t()
{
    while (lock.test_and_set())
    {
        ++n;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(250));
    }
}

int main()
{
    lock.test_and_set();
    std::thread t(&t);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    lock.clear();
    t.join();
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

You can read about [why you might wish to choose `atomic_flag` over `atomic<bool>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329311/difference-between-standards-atomic-bool-and-atomic-flag), but personally I prefer the use of `atomic<bool>` for things like this, as it's simply more readable:

```
std::atomic<bool> runThread;
int n = 0;

void t()
{
    while (runThread)
    {
        ++n;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(250));
    }
}

int main()
{
    runThread = true;
    std::thread t(&t);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    runThread = false;
    t.join();
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Would atomic_flag be better?

Comment: At least `atomic<bool>` is cheaper

Comment: Atomic Flag sounds like a forgotten 50's super hero.

Comment: ``atomic_flag`` does not have  a test operation, only ``test_and_set`` and ``clear``. Signalling another thread is unnecessarily difficult with these primitives. The only advantage is that it is defined by the standard to be lock-free rather than implementation-defined. But ``atomic<bool>`` is lock-free on all major implementations. (Didn't notice that Tas already discussed ``atomic_flag``.)