# Utilization of atomic_flag on C++

Tags: c++, concurrency

I am beginner in concurrent programming on C++. I read about std::atomic_flag and I don't understand where this atomic_flag can be useful. Maybe someone can explain me for which tasks atomic_flag can be useful

Comment: Can you specify your question? Are you asking why `std::atomic_flag` exists when there is `std::atomic<bool>`? If so, [duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329311/difference-between-standards-atomic-bool-and-atomic-flag). Are you asking what atomics are? Then [duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978324/what-exactly-is-stdatomic).

Comment: It's useful when you need a _flag_ which must be _atomic_. If you don't know when you need a flag, or when something must be atomic, figure those out first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[cppreference.com has a usage example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag). It also contains the following explanatory note:

> Unlike all specializations of `std::atomic`, it is guaranteed to be lock-free.

In other words: you’d use it the same way you would use `std::atomic<bool>` but with the added guarantee of lock-freeness (though on most systems `std::atomic<bool>` will also be lock-free, i.e. `std::atomic<bool>::is_always_lock_free` will be `true`).